# Can a Waterbearer relent on his embargo?

Tags: apocalypse-world

> Embargo: you can go aggro with deprivation as your weapon, inflicting d-harm (water).

When the Waterbearer goes aggro and the victim chooses to suck it up, it's a little bit of a strange situation.

If you go aggro with a shotgun, there is a definitive *amount* of harm done, and it's done instantly. D-harm, however, takes up to a week. So there's a weird mismatch where you can go aggro, the victim chooses to suck it up, but then they can choose to cave later, if you agree. Pretty weird! The dichotomy seems to not exist in-fiction.

I'm thinking there are two resolutions to this:

1. The Waterbearer must inflict some minimum of d-harm, and can choose to stop whenever he wants after that minimum amount.
2. The Waterbearer must specify some amount of d-harm when he uses the move, and cannot relent. That amount of d-harm must be done before the target is allowed to drink from the source again. So if they want to be able to relent, they can embargo with damage equal to "d-harm: one day". And then they can reuse the move later, but they will have to successfully go aggro again to inflict subsequent days of d-harm.

2 seems like the best option, since it more closely approximates the tension when going aggro with a shotgun: if they suck it up, they've sucked it up. You can't bluff with go aggro, and you do the damage.

Comment: Please do not misuse code formatting (backticks, four-space paragraph indents, or `<pre>` tags) for anything other than code fragments (read: things that are supposed to be read by a computer more than read by a person). See [this meta discussion for more details](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3086/4563).

Answer (score 3):

### So it takes a week.

I mean, if you want to say it actually takes a week or several days or whatever. There is potentially some deep juju at work here such that the Waterbearer starts scratching your name off the water tank and you start drying out.

But let's say it takes a week. I admit it's a bit of a weird way to think of Go Aggro, which has a certain conceptual immediacy to it, but the thing is, the Waterbearer isn't the only thinking creature involved here. Whoever the Waterbearer is embargoing can also decide, at any point during that week, to relent and not take d-harm. In-universe nobody knows what's going to happen until the target gives or suffers (and remember, d-harm is a little floaty to begin with, so "until you suffer" is about all you can say for how much d-harm you're doing). Or if you hit a 7-9, does one of the other things.

The operational upshot of Go Aggro is that the target is limited on how they can respond by how well the move's user went hard. That doesn't change because the hit takes a week to land. An embargo can be a serious existential threat, which can weigh significantly the entire time.

In the end, **no, the Waterbearer can't relent**. In much the same way that you can't go aggro with a gun unless you will pull the trigger, the Waterbearer can't go aggro unless they will withhold water until someone suffers. Though again, because of the floaty nature of d-harm, the Waterbearer knows roughly what shape that suffering will take when they make the threat.

Crucially, they know if they might be able to talk to their target again, after they choose to take d-harm, and nothing restricts them from giving water after that happens, much as nothing stops an angel from stitching up the hole they blow in your intestines.